# Drupal 7- Passing contextual filters from external form

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I have a form with two fields that appears on each page of the website and a View that has two corresponding contextual filters (arguments).

My problem is I can't seem to make the connection between the form fields and contextual filters, because Drupal Views expect them to be passed like `/path/filter_value_1/filter_value_2`.

I've searched for or tried the following methods

1. Get contextual filters fetch their values from $_POST or $_GET variables
2. Use URL Aliases to route `/path?filter_1=value_1&filter_2=value_2` to `/path/value_1/value_2`
3. Setting the action to direct me to a php file which makes a header redirect (this actually works, but I don't like this solution)

Any ideas are welcome!

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Are the contexual filters visible for the user?  So you are trying to take the two fields and use them in the contexual filters as arguments?

Comment: They're not exposed if that's what you mean by visible. It's an external (to the view) form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.

Initially I thought exposed filters can only be used on the same page as the view.

Then I found the "Exposed form in block" option which seems to do the trick.

Now off to customizing exposed filter forms :-)